# Port forwarding not working in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, portforwarding

I have installed all the necessary tools to up and running with vagrant. I am able to login vm guest from windows host via putty. But when I try to access localhost from host windows os using the port that I specified in port forwarding, I am not able to access that

[image]

Comment: when i try accessing it keeps loading the page, and then displays server not found!  I use :  http://localhost:8080/index.html

Comment: do you have something running on the vm at port 80 ? try with http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html

Comment: sorry, i haven't installed any other program which use port 80. And I have also tried 127.0.0.1.:8080/index.html, but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make it as an answer because it will be more clear than writing in comment:

- From what you show it is not clear you have installed Apache, nginx or another web server, so without that you get the expected behavior.
- From the vm, go and run `sudo netstat -ant` (you'd need sudo otherwise it cannot detect the pids of processes running with root privileges), you should have something that looks like

  ```
  vagrant@precise32:/etc/init.d$ sudo netstat -nltp
  Active Internet connections (only servers)
  Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      512/rpcbind
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1827/apache2
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      652/sshd
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58397           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      539/rpc.statd
  tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      512/rpcbind
  tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      652/sshd
  tcp6       0      0 :::54908                :::*                    LISTEN      539/rpc.statd
  ```

The important piece is `0 0.0.0.0:80` so I have a process running on port 80, and in my case its `apache2`

If you do not see something running on port 80, you would need to install, run `sudo apt-get install apache2` and it will install/start the apache2 service, you'll be able to go on

- now check that you have something that returns on the page from the vm, you can run `curl` or anything that you like

  ```
  vagrant@precise32:/etc/init.d$ curl localhost
  <html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
  <p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
  <p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
  </body></html>
  ```

so here its fine, my page displays.

Now when I go to the host and do the same, I can see the same page

```
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/vagrant/ssh$ curl http://localhost:8080
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/vagrant/ssh$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/vagrant/ssh$
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu/trusty64 and I thought it has apache pre-installed. Now i have run the command netstat -nltp, but i can't see 0.0.0.0:80 . Please let me know how to install apache on my vm,

Comment: editing the answer, basically do `sudo apt-get install apache2`

Comment: @AmitKumar and please remember to accept/voteup the answer if it helped you

Comment: I am not able to voteup due to low reputation points... thanks for all this. It helps me alot.